# transform $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ into the coordinates $u,v$

Tags: partial-derivative

for $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ I have to transform the expression $\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}$ to the coordinates $u=x^{2}+2xy, v=x^{2}+2xy$.

I know that I can write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ but the problem is that if I want to write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ then I'd have to solve for $x$ and $y$ in the equations above but I think it,s not possible. Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: What is $f$?  $f(x,y)$ or $f(u,v)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp It's $f(x,y)$ and how it is defined doesn't mind. I only have to write the partial in terms of $u$ and $v$

Comment: Wait.  You have $u=v$ .

Comment: Yes, that's the problem that I have because I can't find the inverse

Comment: No, the problem is that they are clearly not independent variables.  They are identical.